# A wrong answer obviously means a logic error, but what is at fault in what was thought?

Tags: python, logic

[Problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) describes a certain puzzle that many people have asked about here. My question is not how to solve the problem or how to fix other people's errors. After thinking about the puzzle, the following "solution" was written but appears to be wrong. Could someone explain my error?

```
def main():
    # start has all candidate numbers; found has known sequence numbers
    start, found = set(range(1, 1000000)), set()
    # if are numbers in start, then there are still unfound candidates
    while start:
        # pick a random starting number to test in the sequence generator
        number = start.pop()
        # define the set of numbers that the generator created for study
        result = set(sequence(number, found))
        # remove them from the candidates since another number came first
        start -= result
        # record that these numbers are part of an already found sequence
        found |= result
    # whatever number was used last should yield the longest sequence
    print(number)

def sequence(n, found):
    # generate all numbers in the sequence defined by the problem
    while True:
        # since the first number begins the sequence, yield it back
        yield n
        # since 1 is the last sequence number, stop if we yielded it
        if n == 1:
            break
        # generate the next number in the sequence with binary magic
        n = 3 * n + 1 if n & 1 else n >> 1
        # if the new number was already found, this sequence is done
        if n in found:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The documentation was added later and is hopefully clear enough to explain why I thought it would work.

Comment: why not use recursion and memoization?

Comment: This "solution" uses a form a memoization utilized with the `start` and `found` sets.

Comment: i like your question title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After explaining the proposed solution to a colleague, the answer came to me: this solution does not take into consideration the length of sequences generated outside of the range of numbers being tested. Therefore, a new solution will need to be devised that considers the length of complete sequences.

To test the algorithm, the following program was written. The method works for a sequence over an entire closed range. This is quite impossible to accomplish in the Collatz Problem, so the code fails.

```
import random
import time

class Sequencer:

    def __init__(self, limit, seed):
        random.seed(seed)
        self.__sequence = tuple(random.sample(range(limit), limit))

    def __call__(self, start):
        yield from self.__sequence[self.__sequence.index(start):]

    @property
    def longest(self):
        return self.__sequence[0]

def main(limit):
    while True:
        sequence = Sequencer(limit, str(time.time()))
        longest = find_longest(limit, sequence)
        print('Found longest ' +
              ('' if longest == sequence.longest else 'in') +
              'correctly.')

def find_longest(limit, sequence):
    start, found = set(range(limit)), set()
    while start:
        number = start.pop()
        result = set(get_sequence(sequence(number), found))
        start -= result
        found |= result
    return number

def get_sequence(sequence, found):
    for number in sequence:
        if number in found:
            break
        yield number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(1000000)
```

The corrected version of the code follows a similar pattern in its design but keeps track of values outside of the original range. Execution time has been found to be similar to other Python solutions to the puzzle.

```
def main():
    start, found = set(range(2, 1000000)), {1: 1}
    while start:
        scope = reversed(tuple(sequence(start.pop(), found)))
        value = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(scope, found[next(scope)] + 1)))
        start -= frozenset(value)
        found.update(value)
    lengths = dict(map(reversed, found.items()))
    print(lengths[max(lengths)])

def sequence(n, found):
    while True:
        yield n
        if n in found:
            break
        n = 3 * n + 1 if n & 1 else n >> 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am not convinced that this observation is accurate. Does anyone else have further insight?

Comment: I think the just deleted answer about the order being arbitrary was right. There's no reason to assume that the last value in `start` leads to the longest sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
# whatever number was used last should yield the longest sequence
print(number)
```

Since you're looking at the elements of `start` in random order, the above comment and conclusion are false.

Let's say we're looking for the longest sequence starting at the numbers between `1` and `8`. Since your algorithm's intent is to *"pick a random starting number to test"*, let's choose the numbers in the following order:

1. `7`: this produces a sequence of length 17 and knocks out `1`, `2`, `4`, `5` and `8` from `start`.
2. `6`: this produces a sequence of length 9 and knocks out `3` from `start`.

There are no more numbers left in `start`. Your code concludes that `6` is the optimal solution which it, of course, is not.

More generally, let's say you happen to pick the optimal starting number on the first step. For your approach to work, that very first sequence would need to include every number between `1` and `999,999`. Unless you can prove that this is what happens, there is no reason to think that your solution is correct.

Comment: That is impossible because of `start -= result`. After the first sequence is generated, `1` will be removed from `start` and can never be last last candidate tried. Please see my answer for the true explanation of the problem.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: I stand by my intuition. However, the specific example I chose was flawed. I've given another example.

Comment: @NPE: The numbers aren't actually being looked at in random order (because `hash(n)` returns `n`). The actual sequence of numbers popped from the set turns out to be ordinary numeric order: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...!

Comment: @GarethRees: Sure, there's no randomness in what any deterministic algorithm does. However, the author of the algorithm states very clearly that they don't care about the order in which the numbers are chosen. I quote: *pick a random starting number...*

Comment: @NPE: Well, that's what he *says* the algorithm does, but it doesn't make it true! But anyway, I agree with your insight, but I'm just pointing out that because of the actual behaviour you have to look a little further to find an example where things go wrong. The first such example is for the set of numbers below 13, as shown in my answer.

Comment: "More generally, let's say you happen to pick the optimal starting number on the first step" — this can't happen because the first number popped is always 1.

Comment: @GarethRees: To be honest, I think this whole debate is a bit pointless. Python docs clearly state that `set.pop()` "removes and returns **an arbitrary** element from the set". The fact that your implementation appears to behave in a certain way doesn't invalidate my argument.

Comment: It's not pointless! Remember that the OP supplied two things: an algorithm (expressed in Python code) and a *description* of an algorithm (expressed in comments). You have quite correctly explained why the description cannot be correct. But his description does not match the code (the number popped is not arbitrary in practice, despite what it says in the Python docs), so your explanation of why the description is wrong does not explain why the code is wrong.

Comment: It does not matter if the order is random or arbitrary. The original algorithm was developed with the notion of a closed range of numbers. Since that is not the case with the sequence, the algorithm fails.

Answer (score 2):

The wrong assumption is here:

```
# whatever number was used last should yield the longest sequence
```

Consider the case where we start with `range(1, 13)` instead of `range(1, 1000000)`. Then your algorithm proceeds as follows:

```
number result                                  start
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     {1}                                     {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
 2     {2}                                     {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
 3     {3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16}                    {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
 6     {6}                                     {7, 9, 11, 12}
 7     {34, 7, 40, 11, 13, 17, 52, 22, 20, 26} {9, 11, 12}
 9     {9, 28, 14}                             {12}
12     {12}                                    {}
```

So the last number used was 12. But the longest sequence starting with a number in this range was 9 → 28 → 14 → 7 → 22 → 11 → 34 → 17 → 52 → 26 → 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1 (length 20); the sequence 12 → 6 → 3 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1 only has length 10.

Your approach could only work if, by the time you get to the correct answer (the number starting the longest sequence), all higher numbers in the range have either already been found, or are found in the course of generating the sequence starting with the correct answer.

But in this example, when we get to 9, the number 12 has not yet been found in any sequence, nor is it found in the course of expanding the sequence starting with 9.

Comment: You are correct about that being a wrong assumption in this case. However, the example program in my answer demonstrates that the assumption appears to be correct in a closed range of numbers.

Comment: @Noctis: The reason your example works is not because the sequences don't go outside the range. It's because *the longest sequence visits every number in the range*, and so meets the condition I gave in the paragraph starting "Your approach could only work if". In the 3n+1 problem, the longest sequence does not have this property.

Comment: In reality, we are saying the same thing. Because of the `3n+1`, there is no way to restrict the sequence to a range. If any range of numbers is defined for the problem, the sequence will exceed that range by virtue of the multiplication. Is is not possible to define a large range of candidates that the sequence does not leave. In any case, thank you for trying to help me understand the problem. I identified the error and simply need to devise a better solution.

Comment: @Noctis: we're not saying the same thing! I'm saying that your "closed range" theory is *wrong*. It is easy to construct examples where the sequences stay within the range, but your approach fails. For example, try `yield from self.__sequence[self.__sequence.index(start)::2]`.

Comment: Yes, you have only clarified my assumption. It is a sequence over the entirety of a closed range that the algorithm works on. Forgive me for communicating in an imprecise manner leading to misunderstandings.